# Why is this coding causing a timeout error? (cuboid solution)

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

I am attempting to create a code that determines the number of potential, unique cubes (cuboids) within a larger cube. The code takes length, width, and height (x, y, z) and and should iterate through each possible combination of those numbers, returning the final sum.

EX. (2, 2, 2) = 27

Every attempt to run this code returns the sum of every iteration and times out, instead of returning only the final sum.

```
def subcuboids(x,y,z):

    cuboid = []

    cuboid = sum([a * b * c for a in range(x, 0, -1) for b in range(y, 0, -1) for c in range (z, 0 , -1)])
    print (cuboid)
```

Comment: It does `print` the final sum, If you would want to `return` it you would use the `return cuboid` statement in the end, if you meant `print` then could you post more details, about the whole error.

Comment: I'm doing this as a project in codewars. it's IDE times out every time.

Comment: @Richard That should tell you that the algorithm you're using is not efficient enough most probably. In codewars, the input might be extremely large to test for this specifically on some test-cases. What happens if you use say like `1000000` for one of the inputs?

Comment: I am using sublimeText3 notepad it works fine there

Comment: @HampusLarsson, any suggestions on making this code more efficient? I just downloaded and tested on VS Code, and it works there as well, so I'm not sure what the efficiency issue may be

Comment: @Richard Without knowing anything about the parameters of the tests, or the requirements of the code they are asking for, we cannot really help you further. I would suggest either giving us more information in the question itself, or you ask your question in the forum at codewars directly.

Comment: @HampusLarsson, thanks for the help so far. I'll take it to the codewars forums for further investigation.